# R code to work on genotype data

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genetics

I have this data called `mydf`.

I need to match the letters (DNA letters) in column `REF` and `ALT` with the `colnames(x)` (`"A","T","G","C"`) and get the corresponding numerical values pasted together as `"REF,ALT"`.

However, there are some lines where I have `"snp:+[0-9]"` and `"flat$"` in `TYPE` column.

Now for `"flat$"` lines I want to:

1. **sum** the `ALT` values from as many as `"snp:+[0-9]"` of the corresponding `"start"` ids, including the flat line itself, if the
   `ALT` letters are unique (please see the script enclosed in curly
   brackets for one flat line)
2. **paste** that `ALT` value again as `"REF,ALT"` (`REF` value will be
   same for both `"snp:+[0-9]"` and `"flat$"` with same start ID)
3. get the **output** as shown in result.

I have done this for one flat line,but I need help making the function for `flatcase` so that it will do the same for all flat lines.

How can I make a function to do this for `flatcase`?

> **Code**

```
normalCase <- function(x, ns) {
      ref.idx <- which(ns == "REF")
      ref.allele <- x[ref.idx]
      ref.count <- x[which(ns == ref.allele)]

      alt.idx <- which(ns == "ALT")
      alt.allele <- x[alt.idx]
      alt.count <- x[which(ns == alt.allele)]

      paste(ref.count, alt.count, sep=",")
    }



    flatcase??{

     g<-x[,"start"]=="chr16:2530921"& grepl("snp:+[0-9]",x[,"TYPE"])
     myt<-x[g,]
     x[g,"ALT"]
     unique(x[g,"ALT"])
     c<-unique(x[g,"ALT"])
     flat<-myt[grepl("flat$",myt[,"TYPE"]),]
     c<-unique(x[g,"ALT"])
    alt.count<- sum(as.numeric(flat[c]))
    }

    calculateAD <- function(x, mat, ns) {
      if (grepl("flat$", x[which(ns == 'TYPE')])) {
        flatCase(x, mat, ns)
      } else {
        normalCase(x, ns)
      }
    }


    bamAD <- function(x) {
       new.x <- cbind(x, apply(x, 1, calculateAD, x, colnames(x)))
      colnames(new.x)[ncol(new.x)] <- "bam.AD"
      new.x      
    }
```

The function I have tried for flatCase is:

```
flatCase <- function(x, mat, ns) {
  id.idx <- which(ns == 'start')
  type.idx <- which(ns == 'TYPE')
  ref.idx <- which(ns == 'REF')
  alt.idx <- which(ns == 'ALT')


  id <- x[id.idx]
  #m <- mat[mat[, id.idx] == id & mat[, type.idx] == "snp", ]
  #m <- mat[mat[, id.idx] == id & mat[, type.idx] == "snp", ]
  m<-mat[grepl(id,mat[, id.idx]) & grepl("snp:+[0-9]",mat[, type.idx]),]
  #flat<-mat[grepl("flat$",mat[, type.idx]),]
  ref.allele <- x[ref.idx]
  ref.count<-x[which(ns == ref.allele)]


  alt.count <- sum(apply(m, 1, function(x) as.numeric(x[which(ns == x[alt.idx])])))
  paste(ref.count, alt.count, sep=",") 
}
```

> **mydf**

```
x <- as.matrix(read.csv(text="start,A,T,G,C,REF,ALT,TYPE 
chr20:5363934,95,29,14,59,C,T,snp
chr5:8529759,24,1,28,41,G,C,snp
chr14:9620689,65,49,41,96,T,G,snp
chr18:547375,94,1,51,67,G,C,snp
chr8:5952145,27,80,25,96,T,T,snp
chr14:8694382,68,94,26,30,A,A,snp
chr16:2530921,49,15,79,72,A,T,snp:2530921
chr16:2530921,49,15,79,72,A,G,snp:2530921
chr16:2530921,49,15,79,72,A,T,snp:2530921flat
chr16:2533924,42,13,19,52,G,T,snp:2533924flat
chr16:2543344,4,13,13,42,G,T,snp:2543344flat
chr16:2543344,4,23,13,42,G,A,snp:2543344
chr14:4214117,73,49,18,77,G,A,snp
chr4:7799768,36,28,1,16,C,A,snp
chr3:9141263,27,41,93,90,A,A,snp", stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

> **Result:**

```
       start           A    T    G    C    REF ALT TYPE              bam.AD  
 [1,] "chr20:5363934" "95" "29" "14" "59" "C" "T" "snp"             "59,29" 
 [2,] "chr5:8529759"  "24" " 1" "28" "41" "G" "C" "snp"             "28,41" 
 [3,] "chr14:9620689" "65" "49" "41" "96" "T" "G" "snp"             "49,41" 
 [4,] "chr18:547375"  "94" " 1" "51" "67" "G" "C" "snp"             "51,67" 
 [5,] "chr8:5952145"  "27" "80" "25" "96" "T" "T" "snp"             "80,80" 
 [6,] "chr14:8694382" "68" "94" "26" "30" "A" "A" "snp"             "68,68" 
 [7,] "chr16:2530921" "49" "15" "79" "72" "A" "T" "snp:2530921"     "49,15" 
 [8,] "chr16:2530921" "49" "15" "79" "72" "A" "G" "snp:2530921"     "49,79" 
 [9,] "chr16:2530921" "49" "15" "79" "72" "A" "T" "snp:2530921flat" "49,94"
[10,] "chr16:2533924" "42" "13" "19" "52" "G" "T" "snp:2533924flat" "19,13"  
[11,] "chr16:2543344" "42" "13" "13" "42" "G" "T" "snp:2543344flat" "13,55" 
[12,] "chr16:2543344" "42" "23" "13" "42" "G" "A" "snp:2543344"     "13,42" 
[13,] "chr14:4214117" "73" "49" "18" "77" "G" "A" "snp"             "18,73" 
[14,] "chr4:7799768"  "36" "28" " 1" "16" "C" "A" "snp"             "16,36" 
[15,] "chr3:9141263"  "27" "41" "93" "90" "A" "A" "snp"             "27,27"
```

Comment: Can you please explain line 10 "snp:2533924flat": here ALT is T and that's the only line with that `start`, so shouldn't "REF,ALT" be "19,13"? Also, what happens if the ALT is not unique, e.g. suppose the "snp:2543344flat" line (line 11) had ALT "A" (which is 4), as did line 12 (which has A=42) - which A do you use?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee These are genotypes, done either on human samples or on mice. SNP is a single nucleotide polymorphism. The long number is the base position on that chromosome where the mutation is seen. The REF is the canonical base sequenced at that position, and that ALT is the SNP seen in the population sampled. The output shows a count of the number of times that the REF base appears in the population and ALT is the number of times an alternate base of "N" appears at that position. The Flat line is just the summary line where they are looking at multiple ALT bases at the position.

Comment: @AMR that's nice, but I'm not a geneticist and have no idea what you are talking about, and all that information does not help me. I do see though that you have edited your question, but now the `mydf` definition does not match your desired output - in your `mydf` code that defines `x` you have changed lines 11 and 12 to have value "4" in the "A" column, but in your desired result you have not. Please ensure your input and desired output are consistent.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee... I didn't post the question. My comment was to explain the data to you that is posted. I understand the data, so I understand the relevance of his questions to the data. I haven't coded in r though, so I cannot provide an r answer.

Comment: @AMR ah apologies. However, the information doesn't help with my specific question (the OP made a mistake on one of the lines and I needed it clarified. They've fixed it since though introduced a few more..).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it all, vectorised.

First, note that REF is the same regardless of type.
We can look it up quickly by using REF as a coordinate into the matrix, so e.g. row 1 has REF C, so if we look up coordinates (1, "C") we get the REF value for that row.

```
# the REFs are the same regardless of TYPE
rownames(x) <- 1:nrow(x)
ref <- x[cbind(1:nrow(x), x[, 'REF'])]
```

Have a look at `cbind(1:nrow(x), x[, 'REF'])`: this is just a list of coordinates `(row number, REF)` and we use it to look up the REF number.

Then we do the same for ALT:

```
alt <- x[cbind(1:nrow(x), x[, 'ALT'])]
```

However we have to make sure that if the type is 'flat', we add all the other ALTs to the 'flat' row's ALT (only the unique ones, as you say).

First, work out which rows are flat:

```
which.flat <- grep('flat$', x[, 'TYPE'])
```

Next, for each flat row, look up ALT of the other rows with the same 'start' (that's the `x[, 'start'] == x[i, 'start']` bit), and exclude rows that have duplicate ALT (that's the `x[, 'ALT'] != x[i, 'ALT']` bit). Here `i` is the index of the current flat line. Add them all to the flat line's ALT. The `sapply` just vectorises this all for each flat line.

```
# add the other alts to the alt of the 'flat' line.
alt[which.flat] <- as.numeric(alt[which.flat]) + sapply(which.flat,
    function (i) {
        sum(as.numeric(alt[ x[, 'start'] == x[i, 'start'] &
             x[, 'ALT'] != x[i, 'ALT'] ]))
    })
```

now we just paste together:

```
x <- cbind(x, bam.AD=paste(ref, alt, sep=','))
```

The result is the same as yours except for row 10 where I believe you have made a mistake - there's only one row with "chr16:2533924" and its ALT is "T" (value 13), so `bam.AD` is "19,13" (you have "19,42" as if the ALT was "A", but it isn't).

---

If you must stick with the function form in your question (quite slow & inefficient!), it's essentially the same as what I have done (hence why you can do it without the `apply` call and skip the loop entirely):

flatCase <- function(x, mat, ns) {
    # get alt of the flat row
    alt <- as.numeric(x[x['ALT']])

```
# get the other rows with the same 'start' and different 'ALT'
xx <- mat[mat[, 'start'] == x['start'] & mat[, 'ALT'] != x['ALT'], ,drop=F]
if (nrow(xx) > 0) {
  # grab all the alts as done before
  rownames(xx) <- 1:nrow(xx)
  alt <- alt + sum(as.numeric(xx[cbind(1:nrow(xx), xx[, 'ALT'])]))
 }

ref <- x[x['REF']]
return(paste(ref, alt, sep=','))
}
```

However as mentioned before, if you vectorise it the entire code you have above reduces to just a few lines, and is faster:

```
newBamAD <- function (x) {
    # the version above
    rownames(x) <- 1:nrow(x)
    ref <- x[cbind(1:nrow(x), x[, 'REF'])]
    alt <- x[cbind(1:nrow(x), x[, 'ALT'])]
    which.flat <- grep('flat$', x[, 'TYPE'])
    alt[which.flat] <- as.numeric(alt[which.flat]) + sapply(which.flat,
        function (i) {
            sum(as.numeric(alt[ x[, 'start'] == x[i, 'start'] &
                 x[, 'ALT'] != x[i, 'ALT'] ]))
        })
    cbind(x, bam.AD=paste(ref, alt, sep=','))
}

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(
  bamAD=bamAD(x),
  newBamAD=newBamAD(x)
)
#       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1    bamAD          100   0.082    3.905     0.072    0.004          0         0
# 2 newBamAD          100   0.021    1.000     0.020    0.000          0         0
```

the vectorised version is almost 4x faster.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to expand the function I have posted above.

Comment: It also doesn't add the values "snp:+[0-9]" and flat ALT letters to flat lines.

Comment: Your desired output in the original question doesn't add the values "snp:+[0-9]" to bamAD, so why should I? I am matching your desired output.

Comment: for snp:+[0-9] lines I don't need to add, they have to remain as they are, but for flat lines the snp:+[0-9] and the flat lines have to be added if the ALT is different in any of the snp:+[0-9] with the flat lines. If there is only one snp:+[0-9] ALT (T) for each snp:+[0-9]flat if it has ALT also (T) i.e same letter then you don't need to add. but if there are two snp:+[0-9] you just add them for the ALT value of flat.Anyway, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Is this not exactly what I have done? My output matches yours exactly except for the line you made a mistake (well, since you edited the question your input no longer matches your output because you've changed two of the lines to a different value, but my code *does* do what you have asked).

Comment: Thank you again for your  help!

Comment: If the answer answered your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
# create dataframe
mydf <- as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# create temporary values based on REF and ALT
mydf$REFval <- diag(as.matrix(mydf[, mydf$REF]))
mydf$ALTval <- diag(as.matrix(mydf[, mydf$ALT]))
```

Here in the next step, you said to sum ALT "if the ALT letters are unique" but didn't specify which value to use if the ALT is the same but the value is different. It didn't matter in your sample data set since the values are the same, so in my code below I assumed the last ALT value to be used.

```
# sum up ALT values for all start ID
require(dplyr)
mydfs <- mydf %>% group_by(start, ALT) %>%
  summarize(ALTkeep=last(ALTval)) %>%  # assume keep last one if same ALT
  group_by(start) %>%
  summarize(ALTflat=sum(as.numeric(ALTkeep)))

# merge back into main dataframe
mydf <- left_join(mydf, mydfs)
# select ALT value for bam.AD depending on "flat$" in TYPE
mydf$bam.AD <- with(mydf,
  paste(REFval, ifelse(grepl("flat$", TYPE), ALTflat, ALTval), sep=","))

# optional clean up of temporary values
mydf <- mydf[, !(names(mydf) %in% c("REFval", "ALTval", "ALTflat"))]
```

The output as you wanted

```
                                   start  A  T  G  C REF ALT            TYPE bam.AD
1                          chr20:5363934 95 29 14 59   C   T             snp  59,29
2                           chr5:8529759 24  1 28 41   G   C             snp  28,41
3                          chr14:9620689 65 49 41 96   T   G             snp  49,41
4                           chr18:547375 94  1 51 67   G   C             snp  51,67
5                           chr8:5952145 27 80 25 96   T   T             snp  80,80
6                          chr14:8694382 68 94 26 30   A   A             snp  68,68
7                          chr16:2530921 49 15 79 72   A   T     snp:2530921  49,15
8                          chr16:2530921 49 15 79 72   A   G     snp:2530921  49,79
9                          chr16:2530921 49 15 79 72   A   T snp:2530921flat  49,94
10                         chr16:2533924 42 13 19 52   G   T snp:2533924flat  19,13
11                         chr16:2543344  4 13 13 42   G   T snp:2543344flat  13,55
12                         chr16:2543344 42 23 13 42   G   A     snp:2543344  13,42
13                         chr14:4214117 73 49 18 77   G   A             snp  18,73
14                          chr4:7799768 36 28  1 16   C   A             snp  16,36
15                          chr3:9141263 27 41 93 90   A   A             snp  27,27
```

Comment: Thank you, but why do I get this error:Error: unknown column 'start'

Comment: are you using x (the sample data that you provided, which is a matrix), or mydf (my conversion of x into a dataframe using the first line of my code)?

Comment: I am using mydf as you have changed. I am just trying to replicate what you have done.

Comment: hm strange. could you do a `names(mydf)` and see what's the first column name? It should be `start`. If not, you can rename it, or change reference to `start` in the code to the name of the first column.

Comment: It worked later. I think that was due to some system error with R studio. After restarting the R studio I was able to run your script without any difficulties. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ah good to hear that. I think it cost me the "accepted answer" that you initially gave me, didn't it ;/